# ¿Como guardar datos en una array desde una funcion JS React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy recorriendo un JSON con data de 1 producto. Necesito guardar en un array en este caso sellersList el valor obtenido de la funcion infoSeller  ese push que realizo alli no me guarda datos me sale undefined ALGUNA SOLUCION en cuanto que estoy haciendo mal?
codigo es

```html
    const infoSeller = (seller: any) => {
        const {sellerName} = seller 
        const nameSeller = sellerName
        return {
            nameSeller
        }
    }

   const sellectionSeller = useMemo(() => {
       let sellersList: any = []

        if(productsIsReady) {
          products.filter((product: any) => {
                const {items: {sellers}} = product
                sellers.map((seller: any)=>{
                    sellersList.push(infoSeller(seller))
                    return sellerList
                })
            })
        }
        console.log(sellersList);
        
   }, [products] )
```

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes con el código que has compartido? hay que desarrollar un poco más la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: sellersList.push(infoSeller(seller))
                    return sellerList                         Al hacer esto no me guarda los dtos me sale undefind

Comment: podrías agregar que es lo que esperas que te regrese, un ejemplo del json que te llega y de como lo necesitas

Comment: Parece un error de dedo, hay que verificar el `return` del `map` anidado, tienes `return sellerList`, debería ser `return sellersList`;